# Custom Enter VR Button not working in A-Frame

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to implement a Custom Enter VR Button as described here: https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/vr-mode-ui.html

I can't get it to work. The button fails to show up at all. Here's a jsfiddle showing the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/r0wtq3xb/

Am I missing something? The doc page says to "Style the button with images or whatever." I've tried the following, and nothing works (the button doesn't show up at all):

```
<a id="myEnterVRButton" href="#">
<div style="height: 100px;width:100px;background-color:red;"></div>
</a>

<a id="myEnterVRButton" href="#">
<img src="sprite.png" style="width:42px;height:42px;border:0;background-color:red;">
</a>
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try `z-index: 999999` and `position: fixed`.